# No funciona el boton en el dropdown con alertas

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap

Hola que tal estoy haciendo un botón de notificaciones con el componente de alertas de Boostrap pero al momento de darle clic al botón "X" se debería remover la notificación cosa que si se pasa afuera del dropdown pero dentro de la lista no puedo hacer que funcione.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {

            $("#notificationsBody").append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show role="alert" id="c1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" style="color:red"></span> <a href="#" class="alert-link">' + obj[i] +'</a><button type="button" id="btn" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span ></button></div>');



        }

        $("#btn").click(function (event) {
            $(".alert").alert('close')
        });


    });
```

PD: Según con lo que lei en la documentacion de Boostrap hay dos formas de cerrar una alerta.
1.- con las clases que se implementan con el boton de cierre

```
div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show role="alert" id="c1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" style="color:red"></span> <a href="#" class="alert-link">' + obj[i] +'</a><button type="button" id="btn" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span ></button></div>');
```

y la 2.- Por Javascript, pero al llegar a ese punto me sale un mensaje de error ... 
Error : $().alert() no es una funcion

Se les agradeceria una ayudaa

Comment: Diría que en primera instancia deberías asignar el objeto 'alert' al que luego quieres manejar... algo así como $("'.alert").alert(); en el bucle de creación. De esta manera, será un objeto de tipo 'alert' que contedrá sus funciones.

Comment: bien me funciono pero me borra todos los elementos. use el mismo contador "i" para que cada elemento tenga su propio id .. como seria la linea de codigo de Jquery para cuando presiones la X se borre ese elmento ? muchas gracias pana

Comment: El problema por una parte, es que tienes muchos atributos 'id' repetidos en el DOM, lo cual es incorrecto (id='btn') Por otro lado, deberías hacer referencia al elemento en sí mismo, no a un conjunto de elementos. Cuando referencias por clase '.alert', referencias un array de elementos (siempre que haya más de uno con esa clase, claro) y no uno en concreto.

Comment: Le he editado para que cada <div> tenga como id='' + i + '" osea el contador de acuerdo al numero de elementos que trae. Como se haría para referencia un elemento y no al conjunto de elemento como me dices

Comment: Osea como accedo al button si le he puesto un contador como id                                  $("").click(function (event) {$(".alert").alert('close')

Answer (score 0):

Para esto:

> y la 2.- Por Javascript, pero al llegar a ese punto me sale un mensaje de error ... Error : $().alert() no es una funcion

Prueba esto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // var obj = ['Error','Otro Error']
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
    $("#notificationsBody").append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show role="alert" id="c1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" style="color:red"></span> <a href="#" class="alert-link">' + obj[i] +'</a><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span ></button></div>');
  }

  $(".close").click(function (event) {
      $(this).parent().alert('close')
  });
});
```

Esto Está bien pero debe ser que te está faltando alguna librería por cargar

> Según con lo que lei en la documentacion de Boostrap hay dos formas de cerrar una alerta. 1.- con las clases que se implementan con el boton de cierre

Espero que te sirva

¡Saludos!